# Apache RewriteCond for url with parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

Welcome,

for a long time I'm struggling with the problem of redirecting the url to a separate url in case the a special baerer token is given, I don't want to change any parameter just make a match and send this match to another url.
My setup is apache 2.4.41
typical request from postman:
`https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467`
the redirection should be like this:
`http://tomcat-local:10022/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467`

What I've tried so far
in apache2.conf

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^access_token=(988738467)$
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://tomcat-local:10022/ [R=301,L]
```

The goal is that a client with a specific token will be served by a specific tomcat server

Please help me, maybe I'm doing something wrong, I tried also RedirectMatch, unfortunately without success, all regexes I tested on https://regex101.com/

**EDIT:**

Still Nothing,I don't understand what's wrong. My config

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)access_token=988738467($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tomcat-local:10022/$1 [QSA,P,L]
</IfModule>
# disable some HTTP request types for security reasons
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS)$
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Access_log :

```
"GET /rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73%20avenue%20des%20lilas&access_token=988738467 HTTP/1.1" "complete_addr" 200 200 1225 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4"
```

**Solved**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDown
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)access_token=988738467($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tomcat-local:10022/$1 [QSA,P,L]

# disable some HTTP request types for security reasons
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS)$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Greetings Paul

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts; could you please do confirm if you are hitting `https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467` in your browser? And you want it to redirect/change it to URL `http://tomcat-local:10022/`? Thank you.

Comment: I just now noticed that my description is not quite correct, 
The URL I want to redirect can consist of various parameters, my match has to work only on this particular bearer token which is at the end of Get Request. 
```https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=(.*)&in_line=(.*)&access_token=988738467``` 
this is what it should look like from a regex perspective
all this should be redirect to ```http://tomcat-local:10022/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=$1&in_line=$2&access_token=988738467```

Comment: Sorry its still not clear, please do mention 2 simple urls. 1 which you are hitting in browser/postman and 2nd which you want it to change in that browser, that will help me to understand question more clearly, thank you.

Comment: So maybe I'll start from the beginning, my goal is for apache to be able to grab an url with a specific baerer Token and send it unchanged to a specific instance of tomcat where it will be served. 
```https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=(.*)&in_line=(.*)&access_token=988738467```
How to catch only a match on a specific baerer token and forward the whole request. The goal is that a client with a specific token will be served by a specific tomcat server.

Comment: What I mean from simple urls is: example you are hitting url like: `http://localhost:80/test?test_blabla` and you want it to change to `http://localhost:80/test` etc.

Comment: I get your request(I believe so), but a url can't have `(.*)` in it that is your efforts to solve this I believe, if you can mention URLs in form of like how I mentioned in my previous comment, I will get a better picture of your question and could try to help more then, cheers.

Comment: Okay, now I get it.
typical request from postman:
```https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467```
the redirection should be like this:
```http://tomcat-local:10022/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467```

Comment: Could you please update your question with same details in code tags and let me know then, thank you.

Comment: Sorry its still not clear your current post shows you want to change only DNS names? FROM `xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com` to `localhost`? Please confirm once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally this issue was solved by adding `RewriteOptions InheritDown` before the rewrite rules, and adding `RewriteEngine On` to all the virtualhosts.**

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)access_token=988738467($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tomcat-local:10022/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This will redirect:

1. `https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467` to `http://tomcat-local:10022/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?in_country=FR&in_line=73 avenue des lilas&access_token=988738467` if `access_token` is `988738467`
2. `https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?abc=123&access_token=988738467` to `http://tomcat-local:10022/rest/auto-com/complete_addr?abc=123&access_token=988738467`

Although I gave you this solution, I am still very confused on why you want to do an external redirect to a local page. I believe you want a proxy pass.

Explanation why the `Rewrite*` on the question didn't work:

1. `^access_token` in `^access_token=(988738467)$` means that `access_token` must be the first in the query string.
2. `(988738467)$` means that `988738467` must be at the end of the query string.

With the above issues, only `https://https://xxxdddyyy.dqco1.firma-online.com/anything?access_token=988738467` will work with your `RewriteCond`.

---

### Edit:

For internal redirect to backend server:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)access_token=988738467($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tomcat-local:10022/$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

You might want to have the modules `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled.

### Edit 2:

Your configuration should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)access_token=988738467($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tomcat-local:10022/$1 [QSA,P,L]

# disable some HTTP request types for security reasons
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS)$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. I suggest you to remove `IfModule` to avoid confusion when some day `mod_rewrite` is disabled. Because `IfModule` will cause no error to show up, and it will cause confusion.

### Edit 3:

Adding `RewriteOptions InheritDown` outside the virtualhosts, causes the rules to be inherited by the virtualhosts.

So, all the virtualhosts will be using it.

By default in Apache, the rules specified outside virtualhosts is not inherited by virtualhosts.

Comment: I usually do such redirections with ProxyPass, but the documentation said that if I use parameters I should use rewrite, ProxyPass does not support advanced regex, as far as I know

Comment: @Pawel, oh so you want to redirect internally?

Comment: @Pawel, I have added a solution for internal redirect to proxy. See under the "**Edit**" section in my answer

Comment: Yes, the redirection must be internally

Comment: @Pawel see under "**Edit**" section. I have added solution for internal redirect

Comment: @Pawel try `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)access_token=988738467(?:$|&)`, but I don't think this should fix it. Did you restart apache?

Comment: @Pawel did you restart apache?

Comment: I have the impression that none of the regexes in RewriteCond work, although they should according to theory, can i check this somehow?, error_log does not show any errors,
```
root@105ef78c7610:/var/log/apache2# a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

Comment: @Pawel, Instead, just remove all the `<IfModule>` and try

Comment: @Pawel "*I have the impression that none of the regexes in RewriteCond work*", Oh, I get it now. Add `RewriteEngine On` to all virtualhosts, and add `RewriteOptions InheritDown` to the above rule.